# MS word login issue

Tags: ms-office

Need assistance, I go directly to login.microsoftonline.com and install office 365/2016 onto my mac. After installing the Microsoft office suite icons all show up. When I click on any one the of icons (outlook, word, excel, etc.) it first prompts me for my email account, which I type in. But after typing in my email address the icon (outlook, word, excel, etc.) does not open the program.

Instead I am presented with:

> "An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information."
>   Error details:
>   - Activity ID: 8fa37a1c-40e1-9f90-03fcd961835e
>   - Relying party: Microsoft office 365 Identify platform
>   - Error time: 08 Feb 2017
>   - Cookie: enabled
>   - User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko)

But even though after installing Microsoft Office 365/2016 from the Microsoft portal I can not open (outlook, word, excel, etc.). I can open (outlook, word, excel, etc.) online inside the portal.

And when I go to the Microsoft portal and check https://portal.office.com/account/#installs it shows no Detected installs. Even though there is an install on the mac, that will not open.

Comment: That error occurred message is coming from the MS servers, it seems like something you should contact your administrator or Office support about?

Comment: Thanks - I have contacted the system administrator and they informed me if the Microsoft account is able to open and be accessed through the Microsoft portal then there is nothing wrong with the licenses of Office 365/2016.

Comment: This issue has been resolved there was a change in ADFS that caused the error.